# How do I include multiple parameters in rolling_apply using Polars Python?

Tags: python-polars

For Polars, I can see that we can `apply` with multiple column values using `pl.struct` [here](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars-book/user-guide/dsl/custom_functions.html), but can't figure out whether you can do the same thing but using `rolling_apply`.

I am looking to see whether I can performing a rolling regression, or a rolling correlation.

```py
df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pl.date_range(
            low=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            high=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
            interval="1d",
        ),
        "x": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=1),
        "y": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=2)
    }
)
```

If I did the following, I would get a single value

```py
df.select(
     pl.spearman_rank_corr("x", "y").alias("corr")
)
```

Is it possible to get it on a rolling basis? Thanks

Edit:

I have tried to use the answer suggested below to create rolling regression:

```py
def get_regression_parameter(args: List[pl.Series]) -> pl.Series:
    return pl.Series([sm.OLS(args[0], args[1]).fit().params[0]], dtype=pl.Float64)

df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column='time',
    period='14d',
).agg([
        pl.col('x').alias('x_list'),
        pl.col('y').alias('y_list'),
        pl.apply(
            exprs=["y", "x"], 
            f=get_regression_parameter).alias("corr")
         
])
```

but I am receiving the following error:

```py
thread '<unnamed>' panicked at 'python apply failed: unrecognized data structures: <class 'polars.internals.series.Series'> / <class 'polars.internals.series.Series'>', src/lazy/apply.rs:200:19
```

My workaround for this is:

```py
df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column='time',
    period='14d',
).agg([
        pl.col('x').alias('x_list'),
        pl.col('y').alias('y_list'),
      ]
).with_columns(
    pl.struct(['x_list', 'y_list']).apply(lambda x: sm.OLS(x['y_list'], x['x_list']).fit().params[0]).alias('coefficient')
)
```

But it is outside the `.agg` function (which is fine - I just wanted to ask what would be considered the best way to perform this).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using [`groupby_rolling`](https://pola-rs.github.io/polars/py-polars/html/reference/api/polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling.html#polars.DataFrame.groupby_rolling).

```py
df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column='time',
    period='14d',
).agg([
    pl.spearman_rank_corr('x', 'y').alias('sp_rank'),
])
```

```
shape: (366, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ time                ┆ sp_rank   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ NaN       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ -1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ -1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ -0.4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-29 00:00:00 ┆ -0.112088 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-30 00:00:00 ┆ -0.257143 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ -0.059341 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0.032967  │
└─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

One thing I find helpful when first setting up a `groupby_rolling` is to produce a list of values in each period:

```py
df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column='time',
    period='14d',
).agg([
    pl.col('x').alias('x_list'),
    pl.col('y').alias('y_list'),
    pl.spearman_rank_corr('x', 'y').alias('sp_rank'),
])
```

```
shape: (366, 4)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬─────────────────────┬───────────┐
│ time                ┆ x_list              ┆ y_list              ┆ sp_rank   │
│ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---                 ┆ ---       │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ list[i64]           ┆ list[i64]           ┆ f64       │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═════════════════════╪═══════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [245]               ┆ [246]               ┆ NaN       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ [245, 334]          ┆ [246, 128]          ┆ -1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ [245, 334, 74]      ┆ [246, 128, 295]     ┆ -1.0      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ [245, 334, ... 52]  ┆ [246, 128, ... 150] ┆ -0.4      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...                 ┆ ...                 ┆ ...       │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-29 00:00:00 ┆ [285, 81, ... 124]  ┆ [186, 331, ... 298] ┆ -0.112088 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-30 00:00:00 ┆ [81, 174, ... 66]   ┆ [331, 2, ... 214]   ┆ -0.257143 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ [174, 221, ... 14]  ┆ [2, 208, ... 82]    ┆ -0.059341 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ [221, 276, ... 261] ┆ [208, 40, ... 275]  ┆ 0.032967  │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴─────────────────────┴───────────┘
```

I typically only do this for a small subset at first, just to ensure that the results are correct.  (For the final run, you won't want to keep the list columns.)

### Edit: using `apply`

We can use the `apply` method in the `agg` method.  Let's perform an OLS using the `statsmodel` library.

First, let's expand your data so that we can show how to incorporate multiple independent variables.

```py
from datetime import datetime

import polars as pl
import statsmodels.api as sm
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "time": pl.date_range(
            low=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
            high=datetime(2022, 1, 1),
            interval="1d",
        ),
        "y": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=4),
        "x1": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=1),
        "x2": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=2),
        "x3": pl.arange(0, 366, eager=True).shuffle(seed=3),
    }
)
df
```

```
shape: (366, 5)
┌─────────────────────┬─────┬─────┬─────┬─────┐
│ time                ┆ y   ┆ x1  ┆ x2  ┆ x3  │
│ ---                 ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- ┆ --- │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 ┆ i64 │
╞═════════════════════╪═════╪═════╪═════╪═════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 347 ┆ 245 ┆ 246 ┆ 90  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 147 ┆ 334 ┆ 128 ┆ 38  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ 85  ┆ 74  ┆ 295 ┆ 24  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ 36  ┆ 52  ┆ 150 ┆ 297 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ... ┆ ... │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-29 00:00:00 ┆ 268 ┆ 124 ┆ 298 ┆ 246 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-30 00:00:00 ┆ 275 ┆ 66  ┆ 214 ┆ 58  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 69  ┆ 14  ┆ 82  ┆ 150 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 233 ┆ 261 ┆ 275 ┆ 181 │
└─────────────────────┴─────┴─────┴─────┴─────┘
```

Rather than use a lambda function, I prefer to create a separate function where I can keep my calculation choices all in one place.

```py
def regress_it(s_list: list[pl.Series]) -> pl.Series:
    np_array = np.column_stack(s_list)
    y = np_array[:, 0]
    X = np_array[:, 1:]
    X = sm.add_constant(X)
    result = sm.OLS(
        endog=y,
        exog=X,
    ).fit().params[0]
    return result

df.groupby_rolling(index_column="time", period="14d").agg(
    [
        pl.apply(
            exprs=["y", "x1", "x2", "x3"],
            f=regress_it)
        .alias('coeff')
    ]
)
```

The `apply` method will pass a list of `Series` to the called function (`regress_it` in this case).

In the `regress_it` function, we'll first take this list of Series and column-stack them into a numpy array.  We can then easily pass slices of the array to the OLS function.

By the way we ordered the parameters in the `apply` call, the first column is our dependent variable `y` (the `endog` parameter in `sm.OLS`).  The remaining columns (`x1`, `x2`, `x3`) will be our independent variables (the `exog` parameter in `sm.OLS`).

I've also added a constant for the regression.  Here's the output.

```
shape: (366, 2)
┌─────────────────────┬─────────────┐
│ time                ┆ coeff       │
│ ---                 ┆ ---         │
│ datetime[ns]        ┆ f64         │
╞═════════════════════╪═════════════╡
│ 2021-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 0.6608      │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-02 00:00:00 ┆ 0.002035    │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-03 00:00:00 ┆ -0.013203   │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-01-04 00:00:00 ┆ -798.950143 │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ ...                 ┆ ...         │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-29 00:00:00 ┆ 275.147184  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-30 00:00:00 ┆ 285.589173  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2021-12-31 00:00:00 ┆ 232.471054  │
├╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┼╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌╌┤
│ 2022-01-01 00:00:00 ┆ 231.976641  │
└─────────────────────┴─────────────┘
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it possible to show how to apply custom functions under groupby_rolling? E.g. for a rolling OLS regression, I am using  `df.groupby_rolling(
    index_column='time',
    period='14d',
).agg([
        pl.col('x').alias('x_list'),
        pl.col('y').alias('y_list'),
]).with_columns(
    pl.struct(['x_list', 'y_list']).apply(lambda x: sm.OLS(x['y_list'], x['x_list']).fit().params[0]).alias('coefficient')
)`, but can't figure out how to do it as part of the `.agg` function. I have edited the question to clarify.

Comment: I've edited the answer to show how we can use the `apply` function directly inside the `agg` method.